# Ошибка в коде с библиотекой OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

Пытаюсь обработать картинку в Python. Выдает ошибку. Помогите.

```
import cv2
import os
img = open('/Users/alex/auto.jpg', "wb")
img = cv2.flip(img, -1) # flip video image vertically

TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'
```

Вот такая теперь ошибка:

```
 gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) /private/var/folders/nz/vv4_9tw56nv9k3tkvyszvwg80000gn/T/pip-req-build-9ugsgs06/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.simd_helpers.hpp:92: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function 'cv::impl::(anonymous namespace)::CvtHelper<cv::impl::(anonymous namespace)::Set<3, 4, -1>, cv::impl::(anonymous namespace)::Set<1, -1, -1>, cv::impl::(anonymous namespace)::Set<0, 2, 5>, cv::impl::(anonymous namespace)::SizePolicy::NONE>::CvtHelper(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, int) [VScn = cv::impl::(anonymous namespace)::Set<3, 4, -1>, VDcn = cv::impl::(anonymous namespace)::Set<1, -1, -1>, VDepth = cv::impl::(anonymous namespace)::Set<0, 2, 5>, sizePolicy = cv::impl::(anonymous namespace)::SizePolicy::NONE]'
> Invalid number of channels in input image:
>     'VScn::contains(scn)'
> where
>     'scn' is 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте читать документацию. Изображения для opencv надо открывать через метод `imread`:

```
img = cv2.imread('/Users/alex/auto.jpg')
```

Comment: читал и через imread. ошибка та же

Comment: приведите в вопросе свой код с imread

Comment: img = cv2.imread('/Users/alex/user_169902419/169902419_dyFPfyXJCSI.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_detector.detectMultiScale(img, 1.3, 5)

    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:

        cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (255,0,0), 2)     
        count += 1

        # Save the captured image into the datasets folder
        cv2.imwrite("dataset/User." + str(face_id) + '.' + str(count) + ".jpg", gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])

        cv2.imshow('image', img)

Comment: Вам нужно отредактировать свой вопрос, а не писать дополнения в комментарии.

Comment: Вы уж определитесь, или читаете картинку сразу в режиме серого, или читаете в RGB а затем конвертируете в серое.